# MacOS how to hide the folders and files located on the desktop

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have folders and files on the desktop, I would like to make sure that when I take a screenshot or video recording of a program, the folders and files I have on the desktop are not seen.

Is there any command on the terminal that allows me to do this?

I need to hide everything only when I do the screen or the recording, and then return everything as before.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop false && killall Finder
```

will hide all Files and Mounts, with

```
defaults write com.apple.finder CreateDesktop true && killall Finder
```

you can display them.

You have to invoke the commands from terminal
Tested wit Monterey 12.3

Comment: Thank you it seems to work, I fixed the answer with an && it seems to work.